# Why is this pointer not NULL, despite it never being initalised?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I was trying to implement a simple binary tree in C++, however pointers are giving me troubles. Despite me never allocating a struct for a pointer, it does not evaluate as NULL, and as such, never is actually allocated and everything breaks.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

struct BTNode {
    int data;
    BTNode *left;
    BTNode *right;
};

int main() {
    BTNode *tree;
    srand(time(NULL));  

    int input[11]; 
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++) {
        input[i] = 1 + rand()%50;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<11;i++) { //populate binary tree
        cout << "Populating tree " << i << "\n";
        if(!tree) { 
            tree = new BTNode();
            cout << "Initialising tree\n";
            tree->data = input[i];  
        } else {
            cout << "Setting tree pointer\n";
            BTNode *curnode = tree;
            while(true) {
                if(curnode->data >= input[i]) {
                    if(!curnode->left) {
                        curnode->left = new BTNode();
                        curnode->left->data = input[i];
                        cout << "Put " << input[i] << " in left node of " << curnode->data << ".\n";
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "Moving on to left node...\n";
                        curnode = curnode->left;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(!curnode->right) {
                        curnode->right = new BTNode();
                        curnode->right->data = input[i];
                        cout << "Put " << input[i] << " in right node of " << curnode->data << ".\n";
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "Moving on to right node...\n";
                        curnode = curnode->right;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gives the output

```
Populating tree 0
Setting tree pointer
Moving on to right node...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: You answered your own question.  It is not initialized.  In particular, it has not been initialized to NULL.  Reading from any uninitialized variable is undefined behavior, and pointers are not a special case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it is not initialized.

Local variables aren't initialized to `nullptr` or whatever. They can have any value*, which pretty much means - always initialize your values.

Using a warning option such as `-Wall` in gcc can help avoid those errors, as you will be informed about issues like this.

* Not quite true according to the specification, but an useful simplification.

Comment: You're right! After changing BTNode *tree; to BTNode *tree = NULL; everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Memory space allocated for your pointer variables can have garbage values. So when you check for NULL they are not null. But they don't point to a Node also. That's why you get the crash. You should always initialize.